# Azure Data Factory - How to map SQL query results to a JSON string?

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an SQL table called FileGroups. I will query for certain columns such as Id, Name and Version. In my Azure Data Factory pipeline, I want to map the column names and row values from the SQL query results to key-value pairs for a JSON string. I also need to include a couple pipeline parameters in the JSON string. I will then pass this JSON string as input for a stored procedure at the end of my pipeline.

The resulting JSON string will look like this:

```
{
  "id": "guid1",
  "name": "fileGroup1",
  "version": 1.0,
  "pipeline_param_1": "value1",
  "pipeline_param_2": "value2"
},
{
  "id": "guid2",
  "name": "fileGroup2",
  "version": 2.0,
  "pipeline_param_1": "value1",
  "pipeline_param_2": "value2"
}
```

How do I query the SQL table and construct this JSON string all within my ADF pipeline? What activities or data flow transformations do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way to implement it is by using a **"copy activity"**

Here is a quick demo that i created, i want to transform SQL data into Json, i copied **SalesLT.Customer** data from sql sample data

1. created SQL database with **sample** data in azure portal.
2. In azure data factory, i added the database as a dataset.
3. created a pipeline and i named it "mapSQLDataToJSON"
4. in the pipeline , i added a "Copy activity"
5. in copy activity, i added the sql db as a source dataset and added a query option , Query : **"@concat('select CustomerID,Title, pipeId= ''', pipeline().RunId,''' from SalesLT.Customer')"**

here you can select the columns that you need and add to the data a new column like i did , added a new column "**pipId**" and used pipeline params.

7. in copy activity i added the blob storage as a sink and data type to be "Json"
8. tested connections and triggered the pipeline
9. i opened the blob storage , and i clicked on the copied Json data , and it worked.

**Copy activity in ADF:**
[image]

**Data in blob storage:**
[image]

you can read here about copy activity and pipeline params , links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thank you so much for the detailed explanations!!

Answer (score 0):

If your source database is a Microsoft SQL database, like Azure SQL DB, Sql Server, Managed Instance, Azure Synapse Analytics etc, then it is quite capable manipulating JSON.  The `FOR JSON` clause constructs valid JSON and you can use options like `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` to produce clean output.

A simple example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    id                  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [name]              VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [version]           VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    pipeline_param_1    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    pipeline_param_2    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
    ( 'guid1', 'fileGroup1', '1.0', 'value1.1', 'value1.2' ),
    ( 'guid2', 'fileGroup2', '2.0', 'value2.1', 'value2.2' )

SELECT *
FROM #tmp
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Sample output:

[image: json output]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try including all the steps in a single stored procedure next time.